# problem with panel in ui layout

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a simple layout demo in my rails3 application
  [simple layout demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)
 in this demo there are 5 panel north,south,east,west,center

when I load my project this all panel show in each and every page.

instead of I want to some specific panel in different different page
   give some idea how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code from the simple layout demo all in your /app/views/layouts/application.html.rb? If so, rails will render everything from that file in every view. Since the jQuery code that does all of the stuff in that demo is in that same file, there may be no easy way to make that work with rails. The only thing I could think to do would be to have different .js files for different pages. each of these separate files would have jQuery code that creates the layout for that page, and is linked to that page using content_for and javascript_include_tag. I'm writing an app that uses jQuery UI and this is how I've had to do it. I created sub folders in my /public/javascripts directory that I named after my models to make it easier to keep all the .js files sorted.